Converting numeric representation of date to date format in R
I have a dataset with dates in the format like 20170911.
Normally with other datasets I work with as.Date from the lubridate package and it works out pretty well.
However, when I apply the as.Date function, it does not work out with this dataset.
I get a date for the year which is impossible e.g. 57195-09-11
I don't get it, there seems to be a problem with the structure, I guess?
Maybe it is because there are no separators included like . or - between the numbers?
Can anyone help me out?
As an example
Datum <- c(20170911, 20151107, 20101131)


Note as.Date is base R, not from the lubridate package. You may be thinking of lubridate::as_date() - the lubridate solution would be lubridate::as_date(as.character(Datum)). Also note your last date returns NA since November 31 is not a valid date.

You should make them characters first and them specify the format of date
> as.Date(as.character(Datum), format = "%Y%m%d")
[1] "2017-09-11" "2015-11-07" NA


Perfect. Thanks for helping me out.

anydate will convert that:
library(anytime)

anydate(20170911)
## [1] "2017-09-11"


library(lubridate)
ymd(Datum)

Result
[1] "2017-09-11" "2015-11-07" NA    

